# Eclipse, Maven and Spring Boot Live Load

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot working in Eclipse with Maven.  Looking to configure it so live loading works as in when I make code changes I don't need to restart the server.  Aside from adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

What else is there?  Live load doesn't seem to work for me I still have to stop and start the server to view my recent changes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [DevTools in Spring Boot 1.3](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3#livereload):

> #### LiveReload
>
> [...] Browser extensions are freely available for Chrome, Firefox and Safari from [livereload.com](http://livereload.com/extensions/).

Did you install it/them in your browser(s)?

Comment: That and bumping the version I was using.